# Slick Slider styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to create a gallery slider using slick slider js library. A basic mobile responsive gallery carousel with a progress bar. Everything is running however I'm having trouble with some styling. I want the effect of the gallery center image to be raised above the other 2 (half) slides in the background. For some reason- I can't achieve the center padding effect and the slides are jumping a little when its on autoplay. The widths are also messed up  responsively. Im not sure why none of my styles are working correctly. I attached my html code(without the actual image links) and how I initialized it in my js. I also attached some css that I had implemented (I had originally fully styled it- but I took out the styles because it really got messy).

Any advice how to proceed will be greatly appreciated

```js
//Initialize slick slider
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".coverflow").slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '150px',
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2500,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    }, ],
  });
});
//add slick-center class to create the carousel effect
$(document).ready('.coverflow').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  $('.slick-center').removeClass('slick-center');
  $('.slick-slide').eq(nextSlide).addClass('slick-center');
})
//add the slick container class 
;
$(document).ready('.coverflow').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  $('.slick-center .slide-container').removeClass('slick-center');
  $('.slick-slide').eq(nextSlide).find('.slide-container').addClass('slick-center');
});

//progress bar for slick slider
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.coverflow');
  var $progressBar = $('.progress');
  var $progressBarLabel = $('.slider__label');

  $slider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    var calc = ((nextSlide) / (slick.slideCount - 1)) * 100;

    $progressBar
      .css('background-size', calc + '% 100%')
      .attr('aria-valuenow', calc);

    $progressBarLabel.text(calc + '% completed');
  }); 
});
```

```css
.progress {
  max-width: 800px!important;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #5B5B5B;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FA5927, #FA5927);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  transition: background-size .4s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.slide-number {
  color: #FA5927;
  font-family: 'PT SANS';
  font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--medium)!important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slide-container {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:880px) {
  /*--gallery slider--*/
  .coverflow img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:787px) {
  /*--gallery slider--*/
  .coverflow img {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:414px) {
  /*--gallery slider--*/
  .coverflow img {
    width: 35%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <section class="coverflow">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <span class="slide-number">01</span>
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <span class="slide-number">02</span>
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <span class="slide-number">03</span>
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <span class="slide-number">04</span>
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <span class="slide-number">05</span>
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <span class="slide-number">06</span>
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.webp">
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <span class="slider__label sr-only">
      </span>
  </div>
  <!-- end content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet tool `<>` to post your html etc

Comment: Thank you. I did that. The slick js library links don't look like they work on here

Comment: Your html is not valid - there's a `</div>` in the middle of the `<span></span>` in class 'progress'

Comment: Also, the `<script>` libraries go in the html section, rather than the JavaScript one. The code entered in the JavaScript section doesn't need the script tag around it

Comment: Thank you. Im really working off wordpress and I had added the slider source files through php, so the links I'm just adding now. I took out that extra div.

Comment: No problem. One tip, if you press the Tidy button in the editor it will reformat and helps indicate invalid or missing HTML.  Currently it's missing the link to the jQuery lib.

Comment: `slick(...)` can only be called once, else you get the `b.$slides is null` error. I've commented out the second one. And jQuery needs to load before you load the slick library.  It's running now but you'll need to adjust it so that it shows your issue

Comment: Thank you! Not sure what happened here now, it's not running correctly

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting it?

Comment: In wordpress, I have all this running correctly. The only problem I'm having is that the images are jumping when it slides, and in responsive layout the progress bar jumps down and there is an empty space in between the slider and progress bar instead of being directly stacked on top of each other. Over here the images are not displaying correctly at all.